# Windows Media Player issue

Tags: video, screen, windows-media-player, cover

I have got a laptop Windows 7 ultimate x64 and have a problem with Windows Media Player only with certain videos.

When I open some videos in WMP, before loading, the "Now Playing screen" comes up as usual right? Well, it is not blue as it should be but it shows an art cover which actually is a cover from only a video in the same folder of the video I want to play at the moment.
I tried to use MP3tag to edit/remove the cover but nothing changes.

Here's the image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq98x.png

How can I fix this problem?
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These art covers are thumbnails that are stored in the same folder as the video. The thumbnails are hidden actually. You have to first unhide/show them to remove them. You can unhide using the usual process as in this link...
[Show hidden files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files)

Comment: I tried to unhide the files in the folder but nothing shows up. There are no hidden files in the Video folder.

Comment: @Francis did you "uncheck" the "hide system files" in the show hidden files options in windows. Because these thumbnails are system files and not user files created by user. This is something you should try.

Comment: I followed the instructions in the link you provided but nothing changed. I went to Control Panel -> Appearance and personalization -> Folder Options -> View tab -> I CHECKED "Show hidden files, folders and drives.

I know I made a mistake. Could you please write down the proper steps I need to take? Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry for a delayed reply. Beneath  the "Show hidden files" (after you have checked it) there are options that start with "Hide ......." , you have to uncheck these (remove the check). Click yes for any notification afterwards. Later you can restore the original settings anytime you wish.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sorted it. :)